# What name convention need to be use in images for iphone 4s,iphone 5,iphone 6 ios 9.0

Tags: ios, iphone, image-scaling

Am newbie in IOS,
 I want to create an app in which i want use images for iphone 4s,iphone 5,iphone 6/6+ so i use name convention for these images i.e tip.png,tip@2x.png,tip@3x.png.
@3x images work fine for iphone 6+ but @2x images use for iphone 4s,5,6 that makes my UI very poor in iphone 4s.So please help me to find the solution.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: it's all about app icons, i m not understand what you want to say?

Comment: @Sumit : Download [Iconify](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iconify/id416289784?mt=12) on mac and give him 1024x1024 image. He will create all icons you need...

Comment: i want to know about name convention for iphone 4s not size

Comment: @Sumit image naming convention of icon is same as other images too.

Comment: Please just tell me do i need only imgname@2x and imgname@3x images for any app because iphone 4s,5,6 always tooks up imgname@2x images

Answer (score 0):

The naming conventions would be tip@1x.png for non-retina displays, tip@2x.png for iPhones 4 - 6s, and tip@3x.png for the iPhone 6+ and 6s+.

If you're looking for specific sizes that common UI elements should be, you can check here.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: i already used tip@1x for iphone 4s but it's not working.iphone 4s always pick up tip@2x image.

Comment: The iPhone 4s is a retina display so it's supposed to use the @2x image

Comment: means i need to include only tip@2x and tip@3x images into my project.no need for tip.png

Comment: Well it's good practice to include @1x but you only really need it these days if you want your app to have the right sized images for non-retina iPads like the mini

Comment: Please just tell me do i need only imgname@2x and imgname@3x images for any app because iphone 4s,5,6 always tooks up imgname@2x images

Comment: 4s, 5, and 6 all use image@2x. 6+ uses image@3x. You need both.

Comment: so i need only image@2x.png,image@3x.png not image.png

Comment: Correct. Those are all.